# Javascript: No response after preload of images

Tags: javascript, image, animation, kineticjs, preload

Okay, I now tried to load two Kinetic images, but it still doesn't work. I also tried to put it on another layer and on another stage. Nothing helped. But with one image everything is fine.

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 1600,
    height: 1000
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
    var yoda = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: 200,
        y: 50,
        image: imageObj,
        width: 106,
        height: 118
    });

var imageObj2 = new Image();
imageObj2.onload = function() {
    var vader = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: 400,
        y: 200,
        image: imageObj2,
        width: 206,
        height: 218
    });

    // add the shape to the layer
    layer.add(yoda);
    layer.add(vader);

    // add the layer to the stage
    stage.add(layer);
};
imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg';
imageObj2.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
```

**OLD:**

This is a sample code from http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/. I want to load two (or more) images and animate them both by clicking one button. Everything works fine with one picture, but this code confuses me. After the loadImages function is called there is no more reaction, even an alert isn't displayed. Where and how can I place my anim function?(I will implement the other animation later) Thanks for your ideas!

**CSS**

```
  body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }

  #buttons {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 100px;
  }

  #buttons > input {
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="buttons">
  <input type="button" id="start" value="Start">
  </div>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
  document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', function() {
    anim.start(); //button should start animation
    }, false);

  function loadImages(sources, callback) {
    var images = {};
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;
    // get num of sources
    for(var src in sources) {
      numImages++;
    }
    for(var src in sources) {
      images[src] = new Image();
      images[src].onload = function() {
        if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
          callback(images);
        }
      };
      images[src].src = sources[src];
    }
  }

  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var sources = {
    darthVader: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg',
    yoda: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg'
  };

  loadImages(sources, function(images) {
    context.drawImage(images.darthVader, 100, 30, 200, 137);
    context.drawImage(images.yoda, 150, 55, 93, 104);
  });

  var angularSpeed = 360 / 4; //from this line on it's like the js-code doesn't exist
  var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) { exist
      var angleDiff = frame.timeDiff * angularSpeed / 1000;
      images.yoda.rotate(angleDiff); //sources. instead images.?
  }, layer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing html5 canvas code with KineticJS library code.

You must create Kinetic.Image objects from each of your image objects.

Only then you can use Kinetic.Animation to animate them into rotation.